# Solr wildcard search does not find text

Tags: solr, solr8

Searching for DataField:("track/foo_bar/baz/123*") does not find a document, but removing "track" from the search works and the document is found, DataField:("/foo_bar/baz/123*")

Sample doc:

> Random text.....
>
> https://mysystem.company.com/track/foo_bar/baz/123
>
> More Random text.....

Field Def is

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I've found that if I remove the WordDelimeterGraphFilterFactory it works with the original search but other searches don't.  eg text that contains class definitions  Foo::Bar::baz

Comment: A wildcard search runs against _the tokens_ stored in the field; analysis does not happen when a wildcard is included (except for those few filters that are multiterm aware, such as the lowercase filter). If you want to perform a prefix wildcard match against the whole value, use a string field (or a keywordtokenizer with a lowercase filter).